# CAML Query scheme in depth

Tags: development, caml

I have a plan to develop my own version of the CAML builder app - as a pet project and in order to improve this field. :)

It would be nice to support all the capabilities of the CAML query scheme but I can't find or assemble a complete description of the CAML scheme capabilities. The official one ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467521(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467521%28v=office.15%29.aspx)) is far from completeness. For example:

1. How to use this `<xml>` tag (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms480514%28v=office.15%29.aspx)? There's no any info on it.
2. How to use `DateRangesOverlap` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms436080%28v=office.15%29.aspx) - is it really only for events list? If so why I need to specify exactly 3 fieldrefs?
3. How to use `<ListProperty>` ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff625786(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff625786%28v=office.15%29.aspx))?
4. The `<Membership>` tag (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa544234%28v=office.15%29.aspx) I've found on this blog (http://christopherclementen.wordpress.com/2012/08/27/caml-query-membership-attribute/) - and MSDN again is not very informative on it. It's lucky for me to found this blog post.
5. Why `IsNotNull` allows an XML tag inside it and not just strictly the FieldRef one? I suspect it's because of too general scheme and there's a hidden constraints somewhere in query parsing code.
6. What is `Column`, `LookupColumn` and `GetVar` from the CamlQuery.xsd?
7. What's the full range of options for the `type` attribute of the `<value>` tag?

And so on :) I even have tried to find the answer in the sharepoint.dll code but with no luck - the query processing is in the native code I can't analyze.

There's another possibility - is the CAML query language not so useful s there's no need in full its capabilities? What do you think?